# Can't get while loops to work when printing multiple different lines

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to make a python program that will print the following:

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This is the code that I made to try to solve this, however I can't figure out why it doesn't work. It's like the program completely ignores the "for n in range(10)" line

```
value = 0

for n in range(10):
    if value < 10:
        print(value, " ", end="", flush=True)
        value += 1
```

Comment: you need at least 2 loops or a string concatenation for what you are trying to do. I recommend you try using a debugger to see that your program, is, as you would expect, not ignoring a line.

Comment: This loop will only print out 0,1,2...9. what you are looking for involves a double loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for n in range(11):
    for i in range(n):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: I apologize, I edited the post to show what i really wanted to print.. there should be a 0 on the first line, a 0 1 on the second, a 0 1 2 on the third and so on until there are 10 lines

Comment: I saw your edit and I just edited mine too. check it.

Comment: I just saw that, thank you! I forgot the print() at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(*range(i))
```